# How to do generic merge with upstream branch

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-pull

I have this in a script:

```
git fetch origin
git pull   # merge with remote tracking branch
git merge 'origin/dev'
```

instead of the above, I wanted to simplify it to:

```
git fetch origin
git merge @upstream      # whatever the lingo is to refer to the upstream branch?
git merge 'origin/dev'
```

what is the generic way to refer to the upstream (also called remote tracking?) branch?

Comment: `@{upstream}` - but you don't need to specify that; just run `git merge` and it defaults to that. Note that `git pull` consists of *run git fetch, then run git merge* and that too uses the upstream.

Comment: I was close with the syntax, hard to find, can you add an answer @Torek? I would rather be explicit/verbose with the command if it's just one extra token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you want the literal sequence:

```
git fetch origin
git merge @{upstream}
git merge origin/dev
```

(I took out the single quotes, as they don't really achieve anything here).

---

The description of `@{upstream}` appears in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions), which is quite dense<sup>1</sup> and deserves multiple re-readings over time.  It is in fact a *suffix* you can apply to any branch name:

```
master@{upstream}
develop@{upstream}
```

and so on.  When applied to `HEAD`—the current branch name—in `HEAD@{upstream}`, it refers to the upstream of the current branch, in the way you might expect.<sup>2</sup>  Add that together with the usual "empty string means HEAD where appropriate" rule—e.g., `master..` is short for `master..HEAD`—and `@{upstream}` is short for `HEAD@{upstream}`.

Note that `name@{upstream}` fails (with an error message) if there is no upstream set for the branch.  You can also use `git rev-parse` on any of the things acceptable via the gitrevisions rules, to turn it into a more-basic Git expression.  That's sometimes useful in complicated scripts since it allows you to find a hash ID, which you can hang on to even if the *name* changes as you proceed to do things to the repository.

---

<sup>1</sup>"Dense" in the sense of being "packed with information", rather than in the sense of "stupid"; but also "dense" in the sense of being hard to understand.

<sup>2</sup>"Might" is probably a better word than "should" as sometimes Git does things that are surprising, unless you know all kinds of details about implementation tricks inside Git.